# Should I URL encode URLs passed to the getConnection method of java.sql.DriverManager?

Tags: java, oracle, url, jdbc

The program I'm writing loads connection parameters from a .properties file and uses them to connect to a few different databases.

So:

- Could URL escaping be necessary?
- Does the need for URL encoding depend on the driver?
  -and, if so-
  Is it necessary specifically for the Oracle JDBC driver?

## A bit of (not strictly necessary to read) background:

The documentation says to provide a URL, and the format does seem like that of a normal URL (most of the time, anyway), but I never see anyone using java.net.URLEncoder. Everyone just seems to pass strings into the method.
Granted, every example I've seen has been a hardcoded String literal (so the runtime escaping method invocation would be unnecessary cruft).

[A link to the Sun- err, Oracle- documentation on DriverManager, for the curious.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I know it's very specific. But I like not being wrong whenever possible.

Comment: The best way we learn is by failing.  Write your code and try it out.  If it doesn't work, add the encoding.  If it still doesn't work, come back to us and we'll poke it with a stick (and hopefully help you)

Comment: Well, the issue is that I'm writing in support for TNS connections, and I might not be the last person to use it; I don't know how it's going to be used or what parameters are going to be passed to it. Oracle allows you to basically stuff an entire TNSNAMES.ora file into the dexter half of the URL, and I'm worried some poor sod's going to be stuck with a cryptic error message after I leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't URL-encode URLs at all. Despite its name, the purpose of the `URLEncoder` class is to encode URL *arguments,* and POST parameters.

However you should certainly *escape* any URL passed to anything that expects one. The correct way to do that is with `new URI(null, String, null).toASCIIString()` for the URL proper, and `URLEncoder` for each argument name and value.